# Как отправить GET-запрос на Android?

Tags: java, android, http, сеть

Не могу отправить GET запрос на android'е.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/denwer/php/index.php");
    url.openConnection();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```

Но почему-то index.php не выполняется (должны заноситься данные в базу), и исключение не вызывается. Хотя если я открываю этот адрес в браузере на андроиде, то скрипт выполняется. Что делать?

Comment: Используйте HttpClient лучше

Comment: А читать байтики кто будет? [Reading from and Writing to a URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).

Comment: А зачем мне их читать, если мне нужно только выполнить скрипт index.php, а результат выводить не нужно?

Answer (score 6):

Вот так все будет :)

```
URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/denwer/php/index.php");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    // все ок
} else {
   // ошибка
}
```

Без вызова `getResponseCode`запрос на сервер фактически не посылается.

Answer (score 4):

Есть несколько способов. В зависимости от ситуации можно выбрать тот или иной. Также, обязательно надо учитывать особенности платформы. А именно:

1. Требуется явно указать разрешение на сетевые запросы в манифесте (Перед тэгом `Application` надо добавить `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`).
2. Делать запрос надо не на главном потоке (с API >= 11 будет возникать [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException)).

В итоге стандартный Java способ отправления сетевых запросов на андроиде не будет работать сразу по двум причинам.

---

Также надо учитывать, что стандартный код для сетевых запрос сложен, излишен и в реальном мире почти не используется. Используются библиотеки. Самые популярные: [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) и [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) (В последний входит первая и она используется для облегчения работы со сторонним web-API)

Вот простейший пример для простейшего `GET` запроса с использованием `OkHttp`:

1. Подключаем библиотеку в `build.gradle` (module app)

   ```
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0")
   ```
2. Отправляем асинхронно запрос:

   ```
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    new OkHttpClient().newCall(request)
            .enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(final Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                    String res = response.body().string();
                }
            });
   ```

Таким образом библиотека решает вопрос исполнения запроса не на главном потоке - ответ и ошибка придут в главном, а сам запрос будет сделан в фоне.
Если не использовать эту библиотеку, а брать стандартные способы, то исполнять запрос в другом потоке придётся вручную, используя Thread, AsyncTask, Loaders etc. В итоге кода будет больше и ошибиться будет проще.

---

Указанный выше подход подойдёт для одного-двух простых запросов. Если же у вас много запросов к серверу и идёт обмен структурированными данными (`JSON`, `XML`, etc), то надо брать связку `OkHttp` + `Retrofit` + `RxJava`(опционально). С их использованием, после всех подготовительных процедур сложные сценарии типа `Сделай запрос на А, получи массив юзеров, для каждого юзера сделай запрос на Б и верни список ответов с Б` может выглядеть примерно так (код на [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin)):

```
api
    .getA()
    .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it) }
    .flatMap { api.getB(it) }
    .toList()
    .subscribeOn(Schedullers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedullers.mainThread())
    .subscribeBy { println(it) } //выведет список ответов B для каждого обхекта в JSON ответе А
```

Answer (score 2):

Советую добавить чтение. У меня тоже `url.openConnection()`; проходило, а дальше падало. Оказалось забыл разрешение на интернет. Кстати у вас оно стоит?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так это делается

```
HashMap<String, String> postDataParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
 postDataParams.put("some_param","1");

URL url;
String response = "";
try {
    url = new URL(requestURL);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);


    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
    int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        String line;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            response+=line;
        }
    }
    else {
        response="";

        throw new HttpException(responseCode+"");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}



private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
boolean first = true;
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
    if (first)
        first = false;
    else
        result.append("&");

    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
    result.append("=");
    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
}

return result.toString();
}
```