# Простой http GET запрос с ответом на Android 4.0.3 (Java)

Tags: java, android, http, get

Здравствуйте!
Я конечно понимаю что в интернете много информации про GET запросы, но это все не то.. какой то код показывает ошибку, какой то слишком большой код хотя задача простая а какой то пример вообще не работает.. все уже перепробовал, надеюсь на вашу помощь!
В чем задача.. пишу одно приложение, в котором с помощью кнопки будет отправляться http GET запрос такого типа "http://192.168.0.1/name?dima=hi" и в ответ мы получаем "hello", если будет другой какой то запрос то ответ будет другим, в крации сервер отправляет свой ответ по разным запросам.
Как это можно сделать по проще? И можно пожалуйста код с комментариями! Делаю на Android 4.0.3.

Comment: Почти дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685512/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-boolean-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8402-android-httpurlcon