# Какие способы есть для подключения к серверу с помошью Android SDK

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, клиент-сервер

Требуется подключиться к серверу и получить данные без помощи Retrofit или других библиотек, кроме непосредственно Android SDK. API  предоставляет для этого метод GET, но он дает ответ в ввиде JSON. Тут описание запроса: https://pokeapi.co/docsv2/#pokemon
Как это сделать? Вот сервис, куда надо подключиться http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/

Comment: Используйте AsyncTask

Comment: Смотрите класс [java.net.HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) - примеров использования в сети предостаточно. Скачиваете в строку и дальше разбираете с помощью [org.json.JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject)

Comment: Вот простейший пример GET-запроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169762/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-get-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android/447011#447011

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось.