# Android Studio GET-запрос java

Tags: java, android

Проблема такая: 
На главном активити у меня есть кнопка. По нажатмю на неё я запускаю сканнер QR от ZXING, считываю сам код и сохраняю его. Перехожу обратно в приложение. Далее у меня идёт метод, который должен отправить GET запрос к серверу и получить ответ. Затем ответ вывести с помощью toast. Сделал как ИНВАЛИД, но мне многого и не нужно.

Что происходит: 
QR считывается (проверял), при вызове метода с GET запросом приложение просто сворачивается (в списке запущенных оно есть, а переходить в него сам - не хочет. Без метода с GET - нормально переходит после считывания QR). Не использовал ни асинхронный способ ни потоки (всё делаю в одном как ИНВАЛИД). Мне совсем не понятно как этим пользоваться и нужно ли оно вообще, кроме как "так лучше" и т.д.

Вот сам метод:

```
public void SendToBase()
{


    URL url;
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;

    try {
        url = new URL("https://mysite.com/mainapi.php?test=test");
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));


        String line = br.readLine();
        //Log.d("HTTP-GET", line);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Ответ: " + line, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }



}
```

А вот всё вместе (с вызовом этого метода после сканирования):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //SendToBase();//это потом удалить отсюда. Просто для теста вызываю тут
}

// Запускаемм сканер штрих кода:
public void scanBar(View v) {
    try {

        // Запускаем переход на com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN с помощью intent:
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

        // Предлагаем загрузить с Play Market:
        showDialog(MainActivity.this, "Сканнер не найден", "Установить сканер с Play Market?", "Да", "Нет").show();
    }
}

// Запуск сканера qr-кода:
public void scanQR(View v) {
    try {

        // Запускаем переход на com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN с помощью intent:
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

        // Предлагаем загрузить с Play Market:
        showDialog(MainActivity.this, "Сканнер не найден", "Установить сканер с Play Market?", "Да", "Нет").show();
    }
}

// alert dialog для перехода к загрузке приложения сканера:
private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity act, CharSequence title,
                                      CharSequence message,CharSequence buttonYes, CharSequence buttonNo) {
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
    downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            // Ссылка поискового запроса для загрузки приложения:
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
                act.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

            }
        }
    });
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });
    return downloadDialog.show();
}

// Обрабатываем результат, полученный от приложения сканера:
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // Получаем данные после работы сканера и выводим их в Toast сообщении:
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Содержание: " + contents + " Формат: " + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            //toast.show();

            SendToBase();
        }
    }
}
```

А вот разрешения в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

API использую минимум 22, запускаю на Redmi 3s (Android 6.0.1)

под андроид пробую создать приложение впервые. Запуска эмулятора ждал 2 часа - плюнул. Что с этим делать - тоже не знаю. Поэтому делаю элементарно: компилю, копирую на у-во и смотрю работает ли... Но как только доходит до вызова метода с GET запросом - свернулся (или вылетил). Вообще, я собираюсь отправить QR в этом самом запросе, но сейчас хочу хоть тест отправить.

Comment: Сделайте запрос в новом потоке.

Comment: посмотрите тут как можно отправить запрос красивее и в другом потоке с помощью библиотеки специальной: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169762/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-android/1000275#1000275

Comment: Ссылку глянул, стало ещё хуже. Всё добавил, попробовал код, который там приводили. Все ключевые слова просто красные. Импортов не нашёл. Сложнова-то для новичка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Android есть особенность: http запросы должны выполняться не в главном потоке, иначе будет приложение падать с ошибкой [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException).

То есть часть метода `SendToBase`, которая выполняет запрос и получает ответ, нужно выполнить в другом потоке, а отображение результата в главном потоке. Сделать это можно, например, так:

```java
public void SendToBase()
{

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            URL url;
            HttpsURLConnection connection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL("https://mysite.com/mainapi.php?test=test");
                connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                String line = br.readLine();
                //Log.d("HTTP-GET", line);

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ответ: " + line, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: В Вашем примере Toast не заработал. Поменял на                                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Answer is " + line, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         Оказывается нужна зависимость от java 1.8 иначе не работают лямбды. Это добавил. Ошибок вроде нет, но toast так и не появился.

Comment: Да, `this` конечно же должен указывать на контекст, вы правы, нужно `MainActivity.this` Если toast не появился, то нужно смотреть в лог, скорее всего, ошибка при выполнении запроса

Comment: Да, конечно... у меня ж не https. Поправил импорты и везде вставил http. Всё заработало! Большое спасибо.