# Android studio HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android

Всем доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой, надо получить с сайта json ответ. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что HttpURLConnection возвращает null, я отслеживал через Log.i

```
public String test(String uri){
        try {

            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET"); // Or any method you need
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("dd", "The response code is: " + response);

            if ((response >= 200) && (response < 300)) {
                // We are assuming here that whatever the response is, it can be parsed as a String
                Log.d("dd", "The response is: " + conn.getResponseMessage());
            }

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String bfr_st = null;
            while ((bfr_st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(bfr_st);
            }
            ansver = sb.toString();
            ansver = ansver.substring(0, ansver.indexOf("]") + 1);

            is.close(); // закроем поток
            br.close(); // закроем буфер

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            // Handle any exceptions
        }
        return ansver;
    }
```

Ошибка происходит на моменте conn.connect(); и возвращает null
Вызов происходит по нажатию на кнопку.

```
btn_register_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(chech_good.isChecked()){
                    lnk = "http://192.168.2.123/API/register?act=reg&login="
                            + login;
                    String ddd = test(lnk);
                    Log.i("Tsd", "dd" + ddd);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Проблема именно в коде. Помогите разобраться, спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506132/177345 ?

Comment: Нет. Не подходит

Comment: @СашаГорин, как вы определили, что не подходит? У вас в коде не видно чтобы вы запускали запрос в сеть не в главном потоке. Помимо этого у вас может быть разве что отсутствие разрешения на сеть в манифесте. Что, правда, не решит проблемы с запросом в сеть в основном потоке. И желательно использовать библиотеки для сетевых запросов. Попробуйте посмотреть ответ мой тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169762/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-android/1000275#1000275

Comment: хорошо, какую ошибку тогда пишет в стектрейс?