# Отправка get запроса с Android

Tags: java, android, http

начал недавно изучать java, сейчас пытаюсь отправить GET запрос к себе на сайт, вот так вот:

```
public class test {
    URL url = new URL("https://test.com");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        // все ок
    } else {
        // ошибка
    }

    public test() throws IOException {
    }
}
```

Но, Android Studio подсвечивает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И пишет следующее:

1) cannot resolve symbol 'getResponseCode'

2) unknown class 'HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK'

Вроде всё подключил, но всё равно не понимаю откуда берутся эти ошибки, подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно исправить

Импорты:

```
package com.example.app2.ui.gallery;


import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
```

Comment: У Вас явно какой-то не тот `connection` используется, попробуйте просто переименовать на `connection1` локальную переменную

Comment: `HttpURLConnection connection1 = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    if (connection1.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {` если так, то тоже не работает

Comment: Покажите тогда, на всякий случай, импорты

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Стоп, Вы же даже не в методе все это пишете! Засуньте весь код в метод, компилятор, скорее всего, вообще не понимает, что происходит)

Comment: а почему не используете OkHttp? Он де-факто используется как стандарт

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Точно! Спасибо больше, глаз замылился за весь день

Comment: @danilshik https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169762/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-get-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android

Comment: @danilshik Правда смутило немного, что вопросу уже 7 лет, но другого так быстро не нашёл

Comment: @Apelsin2020 ну вы нашли какую интформацию смотреть, за 7 лет, Android развился с Android 4.0 по Android 10, по крайнем мере примерно. Прочтите ответ с рейтингом 2, он сейчас самый актуальный

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите импорты, скорее всего вы что-то не то импортировали.