# Java. Android. Не отправляется POST запрос с JSON на локальный сервер

Tags: java, android

Имеется локальный простенький сервер на Flask.

```
from flask import request, jsonify, Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    answer = request.get_json(force=True)
     print(answer)
     return answer


if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(host='192.168.10.5', port=4567)
```

Проверка через curl показывает, что он принимает JSON и выводит его в консоль, тут все хорошо.

Так же уже в Android Studio передаю JSONObject в AsyncTask и пытаюсь отправить этот JSON на сервер и совершенно ничего не происходит, сервер не регистрирует никаких запросов. Если я запрошу ResponseCode, то запрос регистрируется, что означает, что все вызывается и работает нормально. Я перепробовал разные "OutputStream" и ни с одним ничего не происходит. Помогите, пожалуйста, ссылки в гугле уже все фиолетовые)

```
        @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL ("http://192.168.10.5:4567/");
            HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connect.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            connect.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            //connect.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            connect.setDoInput(true);
            connect.connect();
            DataOutputStream localDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connect.getOutputStream());
            localDataOutputStream.writeBytes(params.toString());
            localDataOutputStream.flush();
            localDataOutputStream.close();
            //int check = connect.getResponseCode();
            } catch (ProtocolException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

То, с чем уже пробовал сделать запрос:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
```

Comment: Скорее всего вы забыли что-то вызвать. Что конкретно - не скажу, ни разу не использовал такой способ запроса в сеть, бог миловал. На андроиде так почти никто не делает, используют вместо этого библиотеки. Попробуйте OkHttp например, заодно и AsyncTask можно будет убрать. Посмотрите пример тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169762/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-android/1000275#1000275

Answer (score 1):

В итоге сделал вот так и все отлично работает.

```
private void doPostRequest(JSONObject jo) throws JSONException, IOException {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jo.toString(), JSON);
    Request req = new Request.Builder()
            .url("url_here")
            .post(body)
            .build();
    client.newCall(req).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        }
    });
}
```