# Посоветуйте самый хороший способ общения Android приложения и удалённой БД MySQL

Tags: java, android, mysql, phpmyadmin

БД находится на хостинге, общается с сайтом. 
Хочу отправлять данные в эту БД из Android-приложения, чтобы потом выгружать на сайт. 
Подскажите максимально простой и удобный способ, безопасность в данном случае не важна.
Приложение пишется на Java в Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать на сайте php скрипты которые будут общаться с бд, а в приложении запускать их с нужными параметрами

Я делал это так, хз насколько это правильно :)

В приложении:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
...
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(".../add.php?user=1321&pass=2121", "путь/для/сохранения/результа");
```

На сайте:

```
if (isset($_GET['user']) && isset($_GET['pass'])){
     $mysqli = connect();
     if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
          echo "Error: не удалось подключиться к базе";
          exit;
     }
     $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, pass) VALUES ('".$_GET['user']."','"$_GET['user']."')";
     if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
          echo "Error: ошибка в sql запросе";
          exit;
     }
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю это код для авторизации? Могу ли я как-то использовать это, чтобы отправлять данные из переменной java в ячейку таблицы в базе (несколько переменных в разные ячейки)?

Comment: Да, можете. Я тоже недавно только начал, это самый нормальный способ, как по мне)

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос. А что имеется в виду под "путь/для/сохранения/результа"? Я же отправляю переменные java скрипту php (вот этим кодом, насколько понимаю: ".../add.php?user=1321&pass=2121"), а php уже соединяется с базой и отправляет их ей. Так что же там за путь вторым параметром?

Comment: У меня все запросы возращают результат, например после выполнения php скрипта авторизации возращается что-то типо: успешно, проблема с подключением или такой пользователь уже есть. Там как раз сохраняется этот результат, после запроса читаем этот файл и можно понять выполнился скрипт или нет.
Есть и другие способы отправить запрос [тут например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169762/Как-отправить-get-запрос-на-android)

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь и объяснения) Буду изучать и пробовать