# Почему не вызывается AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

При попытке вызвать AsyncTask он не запускается

```
public class site extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... objects) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
                connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
                connection.connect();
                Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                System.out.println("Привет из doInBackground()!");
                for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0; ) {
                    System.out.print((char) c);
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

onCreate:

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);new site();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша задача не запускается, потому что вы её не зпускаете. Запустите её так:

```
new site().execute();
```

---

Также вам надо иметь в виду, что классы надо с большой буквы называть. Иначе код становится сложно читаемым.

И для запросов в сеть есть либы типа OkHttp - тогда и AsyncTask не понадобится. Вот тут есть пример использования: [Как отправить GET-запрос на Android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/169762/17609)