# OkHttpClient не отправляет запрос

Tags: java, android, http

Пересмотрел кучу статей и видео на тему отправки `http` запросов. Единственный код, который вообще запускается из всего, это код, где используется `OkHttpClient`, ибо все остальное, через что были попытки отправлять запросы, устарело.

Вопрос собственно в том, что при нажатии на кнопку должен отправляться запрос, но этого не происходит. Вылетают уведомления, что отправка не произошла. Вот сам код обработчика нажатия кнопки:

```
 String url = "http://192.168.0.107/1/0";
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .build();

                new OkHttpClient().newCall(request)
                        .enqueue(new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(final Call call, IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                toast_fail.show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                                String res = response.body().string();
                                toast_ok.show();
                            }
                        });
```

И сами всплывающие уведомления:

```
        Toast toast_fail = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Отправка не выполнена", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Toast toast_ok = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Отправка выполнена", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я не прав.

Comment: в список моих http-клиентов не входит OkHttpClient, слишком много не очень хорошо читаемого кода. я бы на вашем месте глянул в сторону retrofit , там все на много проще

Comment: Откуда вы знаете, что запрос не отправляется? В логах ошибки? Посмотрите мой ответ тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1000275/17609

Comment: @Юрий, я добавил всплывающие уведомления уже к тому коду, который дали Вы. Соответственно если fail, то он пишет об этом. Ну и вот это сообщение об ошибке и выскакивает, то-есть запрос не отправляется

Comment: Я ничего почти не понял из того, что вы написали. Я не вижу нигде у вас в коде никаких `всплывающих уведомлений`. Возможно, вы забыли внести правку в вопрос с новым кодом? Если у вас какая-то ошибка возникает - то надо её текстом добавить в вопрос, чтобы другие люди могли её видеть. Если какая-то ошибка возникает и приходит в метод onFailure, то с 99% вероятностью запрос отправляется.

Comment: Код добавил. Вопрос к вашим словам про onFailure - если запрос с вероятностью 99% отправляется, то почему же тогда в этом блоке вылезает исключение?

Comment: Посмотри в сторону пакета Volley. Очень удобен для работы с http/https запросами

Comment: А этот ip доступен? Разрешения на интернет в манифесте есть?