# Не работает запрос к серверу через okhttp?

Tags: android, okhttp

Задача следующая, постучать к сервису и в зависимости от кода ошибки (200, 404) выполнить действие. Пошел в документацию, нашел пример. Но он у меня не работает. Что я делаю не так? Он для обычной Java ? Как его использовать в андройде? Будет ли у меня Okhttp работать с Https?

```
package okhttp3.guide;

import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class GetExample {
  final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  String run(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
      return response.body().string();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    GetExample example = new GetExample();
    String response = example.run("https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/README.md");
    System.out.println(response);
  }
}
```

Comment: Сильно помогло бы раскрытие деталей утверждения `он у меня не работает`. Кажется, оно не должно работать по 3 причинам - 1. метод `main` вызываться не будет, андроид не так работает. 2. Вы, скорее всего, не выдали приложению разрешение на доступ в сеть. 3. Запросы в сеть последние лет 10 на андроиде надо вне главного потоке делать, иначе краш будет.

Comment: В этом и вопрос. Как сделать это на андройде? В документации я не вижу варианта под андройд.

Comment: Вот тут показано как решить проблемы 2 и 3: [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169762/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-android/1000275#1000275). А 1 проблему как решать - зависит от ваших задач. Скорее всего у вас есть некая Activity в проекте. Коли так - там есть переопределённый метод onCreate - попробуйте там код запроса в сеть из ссылки выше запустить. Если не с нуля проект создавали, а по шаблону студии - должно сработать.

Comment: Для Okhttp нет разницы где вы её используете - поэтому отдельной документации нет. У Андроида есть свои нюансы и Андроид-дев сам должен их знать - касаемо Okhttp нужно помнить три вещи: Андроид запрещает работать с сетью в главном потоке, менять UI не в UI-потоке и для доступа к сети требуется разрешение в манифесте. Естественно чтобы писать под Андроид - нужно знать основы разработки под Андроид и это не имеет отношения к Okhttp (я к тому, что неизвестно как и где вы этот класс используете в своём приложении, так как `main()` не является точкой входа для Андроида).