# Отправить данные на сервер node Express

Tags: node.js, kotlin, express

Есть сервер на порту 3001, запущенный локально и на котором есть mongoDB база. Как мне отправить туда POST запрос через Kotlin?

Comment: А в чём сложность? POST запрос не зависит от того express там или PHP

Comment: @AlexeyTen мне какую то библиотеку надо использовать чтобы запрос отправить??

Comment: Можно и без библиотек обойтись, но можно и с этой как пример https://ktor.io/docs/getting-started-ktor-client.html Уточните где Котлин у вас.

Comment: Наверное, Андроид. Тут много чего про GET и на Java, но POST и на Kotlin все то же самое по сути: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169762/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-android